# js/jQuery dependent boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very very new in js, and I want to learn it. I have 1 example to do this with js/jQuery, and I really dont know what to do. May be you can help me, by showing your code, and I'll watch and understand how you did it.

I have just 3 parent blocks with 5 child blocks into each.

You can see, that there is arrows called `.left-arrow` and `.right-arrow`. I want to remove class `active` from first child block and add class `active` to second block by clicking `.right-arrow` and vice versa by clicking `.left-arrow`. Eg slider with thumbnails.
And by clicking on any number eg `2` I want to add class `.active` to second blocks in all parent blocks.

Please, forgive me if my question not clear.
[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/js7rc01g/)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.first-line, .second-line, .line3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.second-line, .line3 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.number, .anotherclass, .onemoreclass {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.right-arrow, .left-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.number.active, .anotherclass.active, .onemoreclass.active {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-line">
    <div class="left-arrow"> << </div>
    <div class="number active">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
    <div class="right-arrow"> >> </div>
</div>
<div class="second-line">
    <div class="anotherclass active">1</div>
    <div class="anotherclass">2</div>
    <div class="anotherclass">3</div>
    <div class="anotherclass">4</div>
    <div class="anotherclass">5</div>
</div>
<div class="line3">
    <div class="onemoreclass active">1</div>
    <div class="onemoreclass">2</div>
    <div class="onemoreclass">3</div>
    <div class="onemoreclass">4</div>
    <div class="onemoreclass">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add block level classes to your DIVs and add onClick events to your arrows.

```
<div class="first-line">
  <div class="left-arrow" onclick="moveBlock('left');"> << </div>
  <div class="block1 number active">1</div>
  <div class="block2 number">2</div>
  <div class="block3 number">3</div>
  <div class="block4 number">4</div>
  <div class="block5 number">5</div>
  <div class="right-arrow" onclick="moveBlock('right');"> >> </div>
</div>
<div class="second-line">
  <div class="block1 anotherclass active">1</div>
  <div class="block2 anotherclass">2</div>
  <div class="block3 anotherclass">3</div>
  <div class="block4 anotherclass">4</div>
  <div class="block5 anotherclass">5</div>
</div>
<div class="line3">
  <div class="block1 onemoreclass active">1</div>
  <div class="block2 onemoreclass">2</div>
  <div class="block3 onemoreclass">3</div>
  <div class="block4 onemoreclass">4</div>
  <div class="block5 onemoreclass">5</div>
</div>
```

Initialize a global variable in javascript for tracking which block is selected.

```
var blockSelected = 1;
```

Then create your javascript/jQuery function to handle the arrow actions.

```
function moveBlock(direction){
if(direction=='right'){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    blockSelected = blockSelected +1;
    $(".block" + blockSelected).addClass("active");
}

if(direction=='left'){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    blockSelected = blockSelected -1;
    $(".block" + blockSelected).addClass("active");
}
}
```

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/js7rc01g/4/